# Lambda Latency with Provisioned Concurrency and AWS Service Calls

Tags: aws-lambda

This is a general question.

We have 15 provisioned containers running and our Lambda makes calls to a VPC Endpoint as well as to EFS. We've noticed that during deployments, Lambda duration really spikes. Its also worth noting that we might be over scaled in terms of the number of containers we need.

I understand there are AWS Connection timeouts (60 seconds)(https://code.amazon.com/packages/AWSJavaClientRuntime/blobs/mainline/--/main/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.java#L111).

My general question is: Could the latency be coming from the containers having to reestablish connections to the VPC Endpoint / EFS?

We almost always see latency spikes for these service calls during deployments, and then it tends to smooth out. Interestingly though, if we increase provisioned concurrency too high, we tend to see more spikes than usual. My theory is that most container time out between themselves and VPC-E/EFS, and its these timeouts that we observe as latency spikes when provisioned concurrency is too high.

Is this possible? And is it possible to have too much provisioned concurrency (i.e. we need to hit a sweet spot for the best performance such that they're alway warm)?

Additional note:

We deploy to an alias in 10% / 3 minute increments. Deployments take 30 minutes, and we see these spikes for 30 or more minutes until they taper off. Spikes are more likely with higher provisioned concurrency as mentioned prior.

Comment: By containers, do you mean you're using Lambda container images or are you using something else like ECS/Fargate? I assume the *former* but just to make sure.

Comment: Can you please add some evidence of the spikes? How are you seeing these spikes? Are these spikes application monitored or Amazon-monitored via CloudWatch metrics? Can we also see how you're initialising the client? Have you ascertained that this is perhaps something limited to how you're using the client or the Java client as opposed to using the Java client in another way or the Python client respectively?